# How to get the date from dateEdit or CalendarPopup from user?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I would like to get the date from the users from selecting in the dateEdit form or CalendarPopup after they click the pushButton. Below is my code of setting widget.

```
    self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.dateEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(139, 250, 151, 22))
    self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")
    self.dateEdit.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
    self.dateEdit.setMaximumDate(QtCore.QDate(7999, 12, 28))
    self.dateEdit.setMaximumTime(QtCore.QTime(23, 59, 59))
    self.dateEdit.setDisplayFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
    self.dateEdit.setCalendarPopup(True)
```

and when push the button, the date (dd/MM/yyyy) will display as they filled in.

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.running)
def running(self):        
        dfrom = self.dateEdit.text()
        print('from' & dfrom)
```

if I add 'print(dfrom)' there is no error showing up, but the GUI will **close itself** and **not display the result**. Dont know if it is related to each other. Please tell me where I did it wrong.

Comment: use `dfrom = self.dateEdit.date()` `print("from", dfrom.toString())`

Comment: Try both mentioned and also in the similar question but still the same.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: I have tried again after you told me including in the similar question but the date in the dateEdit form did not display. When run the program and clicked the button and run until at the 'print' only this not display and it is like the program freezing and for a sec it close itself. If I remove 'dfrom' in print the program open until I close it. Not sure if it useful.

Comment: change to `print("from", dfrom.toString("dd.MM.yyyy")`

Comment: The result is the same as before. I dont know why. There is no error. When run to the line it is like freezing and close the program. Thank you.

Comment: I suspect there is another error so it is necessary that you provide an MRE, also I recommend that you execute your code in the CMD/console so that you get an error message.

Comment: Found the error. Thank you.